# Backspace a text string, AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do I backspace a text string. If this was a login
screen, I should be able to backspace one character if I made an error,
and continue my login. I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Please help.
Thanks,

**The sample code is obviously wrong, but may help explain**

```
var log:String = "LOGIN_777";
trace(log);
b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, strangThang);

function strangThang(e:MouseEvent){
/*
I want it to read 'LOGIN_77' and keep decreasing
after one click, it outputs 'LOGIN_7770'
*/
    log += log.charAt.length-1;
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to see what you are trying to achieve. What's the relationship between LOGIN_77 and LOGIN_7770?

Comment: The code concats "0" to the existing string as "log.charAt.length" returns 1 (guess due to "charAt" not being an array?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess you should try something like that (not a lot AS experience, so might require some more work).

```
log = log.substr(0, log.length - 1);
```

Comment: You can just say `log = log.substr(0, -1);`. If you pass a negative number as a parameter to `substr`, it is counted from the end of the string.